# Including Formvalidation.io in meteor

Tags: meteor, formvalidation-plugin

I am developing a meteor app.

1. I bought a copy of the formvalidation package and downloaded the zip
   file
2. Copied the folder under client directory
3. Created a file named  startup.js in client directory root
4. Added the following code

   ```
   Meteor.startup(function(){
   $.when(
       $.getScript( "lib/formvalidation/dist/js/formValidation.min.js" ),
       $.getScript( "lib/formvalidation/dist/js/framework/bootstrap.min.js"),
       $.Deferred(function( deferred ){
           $( deferred.resolve );
       })
   ).done(function(){
       console.log( "Load was performed." );
   });
   ```

   });

When the application loads, I see the error message:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: FormValidation is not defined
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try moving `formValidation.min.js` and `bootstrap.min.js` to the `client/compatibility` directory. You won't need `startup.js` at all, since files in the `client/` directory are automatically loaded client-side.

`client/compatibility` [is used for scripts that declare a global variable](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/structuringyourapp).

Comment: It worked with one change. bootstrap.min.js was loading before formValidation.min.js and was complaining that it can't find formvalidation. So I changed the load order by renaming bootstrap.min.js to g-bootstrap.min.js. Perhaps there is a better way of doing it.